# How do I merge my old like button with my new Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-like

I've had a like button on my site for a long time, and right now it has ~500 likes. However, this button only likes the actual link to the website and not a page on Facebook. 
Today I have created a new page for my service, and even though I've found a way to make a like button for the page, I'd like to know if there was a way to transfer the likes I had on the old button (link only) to the new button (fb page) and also maybe make it so that the old "link-only" button actually links to the new page (right now the link button and page button act as if they're completely unrelated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to transfer likes from one graph object to another.

But there is something you can do:
Every like button in fact creating edge in opengraph which have a page on Facebook, so you can inform people who already likes your "old page" about existence of new one.
You can publish stream updates to the users who have liked your page just like you can with Facebook Pages. There are two ways to get to the publishing interface:

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#publishing

> From your Web page, click Admin Page next to the Like button. From
>   Facebook, click Manage Pages under the Account tab, then click Go To
>   Page next to your page name You can publish stories to your users the
>   same way you write a Facebook post from your own wall: by typing in
>   the Publisher, the field at the top of the screen that says "What's on
>   your mind?" The stories appear in the News Feed of anyone who has
>   clicked the Like button on your webpage.

For samples how to do same thing from code look at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465

Comment: The explanation you've posted doesn't seem to work for objects which are just links. My current like object (the one with many likes) is nothing more than a link and I haven't found a way to make a page for it or publish stories on its behalf. Are you sure that can be done?

Comment: This is due to missing fb:admins meta tag in page code which is required to associate the page with application/admin who able to manage it's page. Simply add one and you're be able to manage it's page...

Comment: It's there. Where am I supposed to look for the admin button? On the page itself? On Facebook?

Comment: Hmm (see the image http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465), it looks like facebook currently removed it from UI.

Comment: see the [image](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/183786_10150105866433553_19292868552_6359560_5484694_n.jpg) from http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465). You can try to get object GraphID from Graph URL by passing link to [Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and than visit http://facebook.com/pages/_/GraphID.